# A forty Percent of prepayment/percent prepayment

Tags: word-choice

Should I use *of* in my sentence?
"We require a forty percent of prepayment."

Comment: Presuming the 40% *is* the prepayment amount, then "We require forty percent [as] prepayment" or "We require a forty percent prepayment".

Comment: Is "of" unnecessary or wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's the amount.

Comment: If you ask for 40% **of** a 40% prepayment, you're asking for 16% of the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what it's 40% **of**... it's actually 40% of the total amount, not of the prepayment. So, you say

> We require a 40% prepayment.

It's grammatically the same as "a ten dollar bill".

---

Note that, for numbers greater than nine, it is optional to write numbers out in words.